# Looping through nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**I want to looping through `servers` javascript object and get the `serverName` and `serverStatus`**

```js
let servers = {
  server1: {
    serverName: "India",
    serverStatus: "fair"
  },
  server2: {
    serverName: "USA",
    serverStatus: "Good"
  },
  server3: {
    serverName: "Aus",
    serverStatus: "Excelent"
  },
  server4: {
    serverName: "England",
    serverStatus: "Super"
  }
}

for (let server in servers) {
  for (let s in server) {
    console.log(s.serverName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you change the structure of `servers`? Using an object in that way is really inconvenient. `servers` should be an array.

Comment: This might help you -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need nested loops. The first loop loops through the property names, you just need to access the corresponding property.

```js
let servers = {
  server1: {
    serverName: "India",
    serverStatus: "fair"
  },
  server2: {
    serverName: "USA",
    serverStatus: "Good"
  },
  server3: {
    serverName: "Aus",
    serverStatus: "Excelent"
  },
  server4: {
    serverName: "England",
    serverStatus: "Super"
  }
}

for (let server in servers) {
  console.log(`Name: ${servers[server].serverName} Status: ${servers[server].serverStatus}`);
}
```

Comment: also for status , servers[server].serverStatus :) Thanks for a quick sol sir